# Sign In using ADFS 3.0 SSO in SharePoint 2013 gives errors

Tags: single-sign-on, sharepoint-2013, adfs3.0

I am using ADFS 3.0 for SSO on SharePoint 2013, I have followed the instructions at http://info.summit7systems.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-claims-based-authentication-ad-fs-3-0-and-sharepoint-2013-part-ii-installing-and-configuring-ad-fs-3-0

but every time I login using the ADFS login page I receive the below error

No strong authentication method found for the request from urn:sharepoint:ontrack.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Authentication.AuthenticationPolicyEvaluator.

[image]

this is the configuration of authnetication policies

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling ADFS tracing will likely give you further insight.  I received this error and it related to not having a custom multifactor authentication provider installed on a particular ADFS node.

Is your SharePoint RPT setup for multifactor authentication?  If so, you may ensure that the appropriate MFA provider displays and is enabled on the Multi-factor tab.

Comment: Thanks Gilligan! I have found the root cause of the issue, I enabled the multi factor authentication but there wasn't any multi-factor authentication provider selected